# linq to xml. read. and assign to ViewData..noob

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have some xml similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <resources>
        <resource key="Title">Alpha</resource>
        <resource key="ImageName">Small.png</resource>
        <resource key="Desc">blah</resource>
</resources>
</data>
```

using linq-xml how can i assign each resource here as a key value pair with the ViewData collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(documentString);
foreach (var res in doc.Root.Descendants("resources")) {
    ViewData[(string) res.Attribute("key")] = res.Value;
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. although I used doc.Descendants, not doc.Root.Descendants

Answer (score 1):

assuming you loadt hat xml into an XDocument, you can just iterate on teh descendants.  here's a quick example, if it's coming from a string:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(docAsString);
 foreach (var resource in doc.Descendants("resource"))
     ViewData[resource.Attribute("key").Value] = resource.Value;
```